# How to protect properties for different roles using loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I was just wondering how you would restrict property access to the $owner role only. For instance in my case I have a Joke which has an Author. The Author has User as base. I would like other "Authers" / Users to see who created the Joke, but they should not be able to see the Authers email, only if the Author is the $owner of the Joke itself it should be OK to show their email, just for the sake of this case.

Looking at the built-in User model you can see that they use the *hidden* feature to hide the password, but using that for their email will also hide their email for the $owner, which is not what I wanted

Let me know if something is not clear.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register [beforeRemote hook](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Define+a+remote+hook) and check if current user is the [$owner](http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#role-isowner).

```
Joke.boforeRemote('findById', function(context, joke, next) {
  // 1. find current user by id, using context.req.accessToken.userId
  // 2. check if he is owner or not, by Role.isOwner
  // 3. remove email from returned joke instance if user is not $owner
})
```

Note: it can be a bit complicated to cover all endpoints that return Jokes. But is there another way to do it?

Comment: Accepted since this is also the solution I have chose for now. I have made a pull request for "protected" properties. See https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/pull/400

Comment: Shouldn't it be afterRemote? Since we are deleting the result's property.

Answer (score 1):

To modify the **output**/results, you can use the **afterRemote** hook, as per the [docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html). The output/results are stored in [ctx.result](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html#ctxresult).

'findById' hooks into your GET requests when the call is like `GET http://myModel/id`. Use 'find' if you are not including the id in your request e.g. `GET http://myModel`. Just notice that in case of 'find', the returned instance(s) (joke(s)) is usually not just one so it is in an array of objects.

```
Joke.afterRemote('findById', function(ctx, joke, next) {
  //your code
});
```

1. Get the id of current logged-in user: `var currentUser = context.req.accessToken.userId`
2. Compare the user id of the current logged-in user with that of the joke owner. If both are not the same (i.e. `if (!(currentUser == joke.userId))`), then:
3. before calling next(), remove the email attribute from returned joke instance. Because sometimes some ways don't work, here are a few:

   - `delete ctx.result.email;`
   - `ctx.result.email = '';`
   - loop through the attributes and transferring them to a new var, except the email, then save that new var the result: `ctx.result = newVar;`

Answer (score -1):

You can create your own role resolver. See https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-access-control/blob/master/server/boot/role-resolver.js for an example. Just add your own logic once you determine the user.